# Converting C array to Swift and back

Tags: arrays, c, swift

I'm trying to understand how to convert an array of Swift structs to a C struct and vice versa.

Once I get the C struct, I use it in functions in a 3rd party  library which return another C struct that I then need to convert back to Swift.

The C struct is:

```
typedef struct {
    double *data;  // x1y1x2y2x3y3…
    // some other variables
} myArray;
```

The Swift struct is:

```
struct DataPoint {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
}
```

I'd like to convert an array of `[DataPoint]`s to `*data` in the C struct and back.

So something like:

```
for point in dataPoints {
   // add x and y to *data
}
```

And also the other way around.

How can I do this?

Comment: It depends. The tricky part is interoperating with C's ownership model (or rather, lackthereof). If you need the array temporarily for just a single call to a C function (_and_ that C function doesn't stash the pointer away to outlive the fn call), then Swift can convert it for you: `cFunc(&swiftArray)`

Comment: I need to get the generated C struct to use as a parameter for functions in the library.

Comment: Oh I see, it's wrapped. Then you need to know how long the C function needs to use the wrapper for. Does it only use it for the duration of the call, or does it stash it away somewhere?

Comment: It is not stashed away once the C functions are done.

Comment: Then you can get a temporary scoped pointer to a Swift array's underlying buffer with [`withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/withunsafebufferpointer(_:))

Comment: @Alexander please see my edit 2. I think I misunderstood your previous comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255682/discussion-between-alexander-and-koen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfacing with C is a challenge, because the language doesn't have a way to express the lifetimes of objects (e.g. no ownership model, no implicit ARC, no GC, etc.).

The correct course of action depends on the ownership semantics of the particular C function. Since there is no way to express these details in the type system, you'll have to carefully read the documentation of the C function to understand what it does.

I'll give examples of each.

As a common setup, I'm imagining that you have:

```swift
// Imported C type
struct myArray {
    // Not sure what this type is exactly, but I'm assuming it's this.
    let data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>
}

// your native Swift type
struct DataPoint {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
}

let samplePoints = [
    DataPoint(x: 1, y: 2),
    DataPoint(x: 3, y: 4),
    DataPoint(x: 5, y: 6),
]
```

## Case 1: the C function needs to borrow

Some C functions only need access temporary access to an argument object, for the lifetime for the function call. Either they don't need to access the object after returning, or if they do, they make their own copy.

In this case Swift is the owner, responsible for clean-up (which is easy because of ARC).

Here's an example of this case, and what is and isn't allowed:

```c
double *someGlobal = null;

// A function that temporarily borrows `param` for the lifetime of the call,
// without owning or freeing it.
void borrowingFn(myArray param) {
    // ✅ Allowed
    // The C function is using its temporary access to create a copy.
    // From there, it can do anything it wants with its new copy,
    // it is its responsibility to `free()` it eventually.
    someGlobal = myArray_copy(param).data;
    
    // ❌ Not allowed in this case!
    // Smuggling the `param` out of this scope would end up with a dangling pointer
    someGlobal = param; //  

    // ❌ Not allowed in this case!
    // Swift will auto-free. If the C code frees it itself, then you'll get a double-free error.
    free(param.data);
}
```

These are the easiest to deal with, because you can use functions that give scoped-access to a pointer.

```swift
let result = samplePoints.flatMap { [$0.x, $0.y] }.withUnsafeBufferPointer { p in
    // ℹ️ The pointer passed as an argument to `body` is valid only during the execution
    // of `withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`.
    // ⚠️ Do not store or return the pointer for later use.
    let temporaryCStruct = myArray(data: p.baseAddress!)
    return borrowingFn(temporaryCStruct)
}
```

The `samplePoints.flatMap { [$0.x, $0.y] }` express will allocate a new buffer for a new Swift Array. It'll will automatically be deallocated at the end of this expression (since there are no strong references made to keep the array alive).

## Case 2: the C function takes ownership

Some C functions take ownership of an object you give them, and they'll be responsible for cleaning it up themselves. Typically, once you hand over the object, you can no longer use it yourself. Common examples are something like `someType_free()`, which takes a pointer to a `someType` object, frees its members, then frees the object itself. After the call, the pointer is dangling, and it would be illegal to access it from Swift.

In this case, C is the owner, and is responsible for cleanup (manually, via `free()`).

Here's an example of this case, and what is and isn't allowed:

```c
double *someGlobal = null;

// A function that takes permenant ownership of `param`.
void consumingFn(myArray param) {
    // ✅ Allowed
    // This function has assumped ownership of the parameter.
    // It's free to hold onto it as long as it wants.
    // It is its responsibility to `free()` it eventually.
    someGlobal = param; //  

    // ✅ Allowed
    // The Swift code needs to make sure that it doesn't also try
    // to `free()`, otherweise you'll get a double-free error.
    free(param.data);
}
```

These are a bit trickier to deal with. You need to create your own copied memory to hand over to the consuming function. Scoped access *will not work*, because of the automatic `free()` that Swift would do.

```swift
// Allocate a brand new buffer to eventually hand over.
let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: samplePoints.count * 2)

// ❌ Do not deallocate this yourself! We're handing it over to `consumingFn`.
// It is *its* job to clean it up.
defer { buffer.deallocate() } // 

// Copy over our Swift Doubles into the new buffer.
_ = buffer.initialize(from: samplePoints.lazy.flatMap { [$0.x, $0.y] })

// Wrap up the new buffer into a C struct.
let cStructThatNeedsToBeFreed = myArray(data: buffer.baseAddress!)

// Permenantly hand over control to the C function.
consumingFn(cStructThatNeedsToBeFreed)

// ⚠️ Depending on the exact semantics of the C function, it might be illegal
// to use the value after calling `consumingFn`!
doSomething(with: cStructThatNeedsToBeFreed) //
```

## Case 3: C function has shared ownership

This is the trickiest case, similar to case 2, but without a clear owner. Swift code and C code share simultaneous access to some objects, requiring manual cleanup at some point in the future. The approach would be similar to case 2, but you might need to call `deallocate()` from the Swift code.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander for this detailed explanation. Case 2 is what I ended up using. Final step is to convert the returned `myArray` from a library function back to `[DataPoint]`.

Comment: That's kind of its own separate question, and is a similar matter of whether you want your Swift code to borrow a C-owned object, to take ownership from C, or have shared access. Also, how often are you going back-and-forth between C and Swift in this case?

Comment: Sounds good, I'll see what I can get come up with and write a new question if needed. I'm going back and forth only once for each operation, although an operation may involve more than one array at the time. But always Swift -> C -> Swift.

Comment: @koen If you're not doing that too many times, than it could be just fine to copy the buffers back/forth in each direction. If you need to do it a lot, it might be worth investigating some scheme that has less bridging costs. In the meanwhile, could you please delete your other answer? As I mentioned, it compiles and gives a false sense of correctness, but is actually UB and utterly broken

Comment: I appreciate your answer and explanations. In the end, I was able to convert the C code to Swift so no longer need to do the array switcheroo.